# how to lookup a city name by facebook's City Id?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, city

Or, I'm fine downloading all the cities in a country, and searching in memory.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple but not (obviously) documented... Just query `http://graph.facebook.com/106078429431815` with `106078429431815` being the city id (London in this example).